# How to make a Python class version aware?

Tags: python, git, pyspark, devops

I am running a series of models, implemented as SparkML transformers, whose execution I like to monitor. Specifically, I like to monitor which version of the model is used in specific task executions.

I imagine recording the version of the transformer class during run-time execution for monitoring and possibly fetching a more up-to-date version - similar to the version information for [AssemblyVersionAttribute in .Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=net-5.0). Such information is both important for model efficacy monitoring as well as for certain regulatory settings.

What is the most pythonic way to accomplish this?

I looked at [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) and related modules without finding a suitable method. I [considered git-hooks](https://dev.to/okeeffed/semantic-versioning-in-python-with-git-hooks-5c5a) to write version tags into my classes. However, the approach I found disrupts development workflow, makes commits cumbersome and I am not clear how to finally retrieve information at run-time. Also, I am aware that such version information can be retrieved for packaging but I wish to have version information at the class level.

**EDIT:**
The version information should not need to be manually maintained but derived from other build artifacts, e.g., git, language features

Answer (score 1):

You can hardcode it as an attribute of your class:

```py
class MyCLass:
    version="1.1.1"
```

You will be able to bump the version when you update your class.

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for a solution that derives the information from build artefacts.